# ¿Se puede implementar una App de Unity con otra App de Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity3d, unity, unity2d

Tengo una App de realidad aumentada con Unity y tengo otra App con Android Studio y quiero implementar la App de Unity a Android Studio, no se si existe alguna forma de implementar este proyecto o en ese caso que sería lo mejor para hacer. Tengo entendido que uno puede exportar el proyecto de Unity a Android y configurar el Manifest de Android para así permitir código de Unity pero realmente no sé si se pueda ya lo he intentado y no funciona, quisiera saber si hay otra forma o que solución sería más fácil.

Comment: Como lo has intentado, agrega el código esencial, revisa[ask], saludos.